# python crashes after running list comprehension with error code 0xc0000409 in module ucrtbase.dll

Tags: python, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

Python code in notebook below:

```
**from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

def ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path):
    img = preprocess_input(path_to_tensor(img_path))
    return np.argmax(ResNet50_model.predict(img))

def dog_detector(img_path):
    prediction = ResNet50_predict_labels(img_path)
    return ((prediction <= 268) & (prediction >= 151))** 


dog_pic_sum_from_human_files = np.sum([1 if dog_detector(img_path1) \
                          else 0 for img_path1 in list(human_files_short)])

dog_pic_sum = np.sum([1 if dog_detector(img_path2) \
                          else 0 for img_path2 in list(dog_files_short)])**
```

Windows error log below:

> error app: python.exe，version: 3.5.3150.1013，timestamp: 0x58ae5709
>
> module ucrtbase.dll version: 10.0.15063.413，timestamp: 0x5ba8b66e
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000409
>
> offset: 0x00000000000734be
>
> PID: 0x4c4
>
> App path: D:\softinstalled\task\anaconda3\envs\dog-project\python.exe
>
> Module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
>
> Report ID: 93719113-f242-4e45-948d-9df8437fe2ac

Comment: Please Someone  helpe me as I've failed for almost a day

Comment: Where do you define `human_files_short` and `dog_files_short`?

Comment: it doesn't  matter where it is defined. And the human_files_short and dog_files_short is ran well in the list comprehension above. And they all can be ran good in the windows-7. But in windows-10, python crashes.

Comment: Do you have a python stack trace anywhere?

Comment: there is no stack trace. just a dialog python has already crashed or something.

Comment: Ok. You are getting a *stack buffer overflow*, as indicated by the exception code `0xc0000409`. If you can point me to where in the code it all goes wrong, I might be able to help you. Have you tried running it directly with python and not in jupyter?

Comment: It ran in the jupyter but it ran very well in the windows-7 which has smaller memory and lower cpu than windows-10 where python came to crash now

Comment: Ok, good luck finding an answer.

Comment: In a nutshell, the code above cause python to crash in Windows-10 but ran well in Windows-7. Why? The same project, the same code.